# Is there some model trained over algebraic finite fields?

Tags: machine-learning-model

I am wondering if at this moment there are machine learning algorithms whose training algorithm is performed over finite fields. You can assume that the training dataset is in some finite field too.

Do you know some examples of it?

Comment: Everything is done with finite everything. So yes, all models and all datasets

Comment: @Warlax56 I edited the question title for more clarity. I'm not talking about finite memory or finite representation. I'm talking about algorithms over _algebraic_ finite fields directly.

Comment: I'm not sure if this what you mean but are you talking about symbolic learning, as opposed to statistical learning? Nowadays *machine learning* is used as a synonym of *statistical machine learning*, but technically there are algorithms which perform symbolic learning. It's a whole different concept though.

Comment: What would be your objective? ML is highly applied and problem specific, so depending on what your goals are, possibly.

Comment: @Warlax56 In this case, I can add an additional feature to a machine learning model whose computational domain are the finite fileds. Commonly, to apply this feature, you need to put your machine learning model in some finite state (for example, fixed-point arithmetic) and then change it to finite fields, but I want to get rid of this transformation and study models that works directly over finite fields. That's my idea.